# Solution to equation $-u''=\cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The question tells us to solve

$-u''=\cos(x)$

$u(0)=0, u'(0)=1$

I have not solved these types of problems in a long time so my first attempt is that

$u''=d^2u/dx^2$.

I'm not sure if that's what's actually implied here but using that I simply integrated twice,

$u''=-\cos(x)$

$u'=-\sin(x)+c$

$u=\cos(x)+cx+d$

Using initial conditions:
$u(0)=1+d=0, d=-1$

$u'(0)=c=1$

So my answer is,

$u(x)=\cos(x)+x-1$

Is this actually the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That's the way I would have done it.